# How to convert web application to a desktop application

Tags: web, coldfusion, desktop-application, converters

Does anyone know of a product that can be purchased and installed locally that will convert a web application to a desktop app. I am talking something that will screen **scrape** everything so that no database connection is going to be required. This is a US govt product that is being archived so the we cannot put it in the cloud, it is also old and written in ColdFusion. All we need is a screen **scrape** of all the screens links etc to get it kind archived in a way that if someone wanted to see a specific screen they can launch it with out having to run a full cold fusion server just to run an archived 15 year old app .

Comment: Is the number of screens small enough to do it manually - as in run the app and save every page as an html file?

Comment: unfortunately, no its a huge app! that has been around for a long time

Comment: sounds like a good use case for a virtual machine

Comment: Does it use a backend database? That could potentially make it unfeasible to screen scrape to static html...

Answer (score 2):

> just to run an archived 15 year old app .

Do they just want static view of the screens or do they want to actually interact with the application as it is now? If they just want screen-scraped static screens, well you could probably find something to automate that.

If you want still access the whole application as-is,

- you'll need a server (even if it's run locally on a desktop)
- you'll need the database (which you might be able to run locally on a desktop depending on size).

> This is a US govt product that is being archived so the we cannot put it in the cloud

Why not? Amazon is certified for government projects. You could spin up an EC2 instance with a snapshot of the current CF server. You can do the same with the existing DB. Odds are, the version of CF you're using is past end of life so no more security updates are coming.

Restrict access to these servers to VPN connections and make sure the domain is accessible only via VPN as well. This will isolate the application from the public Internet, which should further satisfy security requirements, and allow the app to run as-is.

You could even spin down those servers until someone needs to access the application so you're only paying for server while the app is in use and not pay for servers while the app sits around doing nothing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Reasons for not going with amazon I cant detail here! but they just want a static copy of it as is now, I found some website down loaders I will try and see if that works. I suppose I can write something that can screen capture each and every page , I just wish I did not have to.